# Hosting a React application in AWS S3 without any backend

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am trying to host a view, I have build the application using create react app, so I don't have any back end for the application. I am just consuming the services.

I have fair idea of using Node and React with Docker and exposing a single port and serving the html file through Node.js.

But in this sample application I am just consuming the services and rendering the UI.

For this sample UI do we need to use Docker, I have read through some docs and found out that its better host this single html file in s3, since AWS S3 is made for file retrieving and hosting.

So how can I build the application and how can host this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build the application run the command `npm run build`, this will be preconfigure if you are using create-react-app for your application setup.

For deployment go to your AWS console,

1. Create a new bucket
2. Upload the contents of your generated build folder to the root of the new bucket.
3. In your bucket properties, there would be an option to setup static website hosting, select that.
4. Make sure the permissions of you bucket and files are correct and accessible

I would suggest using cloudfront on top of the s3 bucket.

Read this [blog](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/deploying-a-react-app-to-s3/) for more details,

Comment: one doubt, so in the article basically every time we are building and do the sync, is there any way i can do these using Dockerfile so just need to make jenkins job to hit the Dockerfile and it will do automatically any idea on this, So what i am trying to achieve is basically there will be a jenkins job, where i will mention the repo and branch on jenkins configuration and trigger the build, that will hit the branch and take the repo and find the Dockerfile and build it . So Inside Dockerfile i will do the npm run build and sync with s3

Comment: So for the first time i need to upload the file from the second time there wont be any upload only just sync, is thats possible

Comment: Either you will have to setup CI/CD or you can directly push the build folder using aws cli. 

If you are looking to automate it, heres a blog which you can refer to, https://blog.dakshgautam.com/travis/

Comment: but the article is related to using travis, is there any article related to the jenkins

Answer (score 2):

If you want to host this react app on AWS S3, you can compile the code using `npm run build` or `yarn build` [Building production build](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build). It should create a build folder with all the production ready files. You then need to upload these files to S3 bucket, which you want to host your website. After this website should be available at url associated with S3 bucket

Here is the documentation for [S3 hosting static website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting). Firebase is very easy to setup with your react app.

Once setup you run `npm run-script build` to build for production and then do `firebase deploy` and you're done!

P.S: Firebase also works well with node.js backends if you had one.